# Declaration of n-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, fortran

Is there a way I can declare an array which will be able to allocate any number of dimensions (in any shape) later in the code? Something like a the classic deferred shape but bearing in mind I do not know the rank, shape or size during declaration. For example, something similar to

```
real, allocatable :: a(:) 
integer, parameter :: sh = [4,2,2]

allocate(a(sh))
```

which does not throw an error (of course it does in this case).

Comment: I think rank remapping of array pointers is pretty handy for this (allocate( a(16) ); p( 1:4, 1:4 ) => a, or q( 1:4, 1:2, 1:2 ) => a, where p and q are 2d and 3d array pointers)

Comment: This actually useful, thanks. I have not seen this in the linked duplicates. @francescalus